# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lticpp

Tags: linux, tinyxml

I have a project written in c++ and I want to compile it on Linux using a makefile. 
But I have an error when executing a `make` command on ubuntu, the error is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lticpp
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And in makefile there is the following commands for `ticpp` library:

```
    # Flags to enable the use of the TinyXML library
TINYXMLHOME = ../libs/ticpp
WKXLIBS_TINYXML_FLAGS = -I$(TINYXMLHOME)/ -L$(TINYXMLHOME)/lib
CFLAGS += -I$(TINYXMLHOME)/
#LDFLAGS += -lticpp 
LDFLAGS += -L$(TINYXMLHOME) -lticpp
```

so, is there any idea about this? 
Thanks in advance